# Extracting data in a specific order from a data dump on a separate worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros

I am trying to extract data from the "USD-ZAR" worksheet. The code works perfectly. The only problem is that the data is in descending order as opposed to ascending order which would be preferred.
How would I go about fixing this issue?

This is the data dump where the data is being extracted from

[image: Data Dump]

This is the extracted data, instead of begining with th emost recent data i.e. February, 28. I want to begin with the first date i.e. February, 3.

[image: Output]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Sheets("Filter").Select

    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        Call FilterMacro
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B3")) Is Nothing Then
        Call FilterMacro
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B6")) Is Nothing Then
        Call FilterMacro
    End If

End Sub


Sub FilterMacro()


'creating variables
Dim lrow, lrowFilter, frow As Long
Dim cell, rngDate As Range
Dim period, year As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim result As String
Dim ColCurrency As Long


'delete old list
Sheets("Filter").Range("C2:D1000").Value = ""

'define period and year
period = Sheets("Filter").Range("B3").Value
year = Sheets("Filter").Range("B2").Value

'define worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("USD-ZAR")

'define first and last rows
frow = 1
lrowFilter = Sheets("Filter").Range("B65000").End(xlUp).Row
lrow = Sheets("USD-ZAR").Range("B65000").End(xlUp).Row


'define ranges
Set rngDate = Sheets("USD-ZAR").Range(Sheets("USD-ZAR").Cells(frow, "C"), _
Sheets("USD-ZAR").Cells(lrow, "C"))


'select currency pairs
If Sheets("Filter").Range("B6").Value = "USD/ZAR" Then
    ColCurrency = 2

ElseIf Sheets("Filter").Range("B6").Value = "EUR/HUF" Then
    ColCurrency = 2

ElseIf Sheets("Filter").Range("B6").Value = "USD/EUR" Then
    ColCurrency = 4
End If



'Cycle
For Each cell In rngDate

  'Condition
  If cell.Value Like year & "*" & period & "*" Then
    lrowFilter = Sheets("Filter").Range("C65000").End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets("Filter").Cells(lrowFilter + 1, "C").Value = _
        ws.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column).Value

        Sheets("Filter").Cells(lrowFilter + 1, "D") = _
        ws.Cells(cell.Row, ColCurrency).Value
  End If

Next cell


'Error handling
If Sheets("Filter").Range("C2").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "No data. Please select another period!"
End If

Sheets("Filter").Select

End Sub

Sub Create_Line_Chart()
 'create a line chart in excel with this macro

 ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
 ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Filter'!$C$2:$D$22")
 ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine

End Sub
```

Comment: Would U like to extract only dates in Ascending order from sheet `USD-ZAR` or more columns ?

Comment: I would like to extract the data in ascending order from USD-ZAR

Answer (score -1):

*I would like to suggest two possible methods, one is to extract Text data & another is pull Date/Numbers.*

**Method 1:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Put numbers in series in helper column ( here is `col E` ).
- An array (CSE) formula in cell `D111`:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(USD-ZAR!$C$111:$C$122, MATCH(SMALL(IF($D$109=USD-ZAR!$A$111:$A$122, $E$111:$E$122, ""), ROW(A1)), IF($D$109=USD-ZAR!$A$111:$A$122, $E$111:$E$122, ""),0)),"")}
  ```

**N.B.**

- You may extend list ( for helper Column ) as your need.
- Cell `D109` has criteria to filter data while extracting form `USD-ZAR sheet`.
- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.
- For neatness later on you may hide `Helper Column E`.
- Adjust cell references in formula as needed.

---

**Method 2:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter `03/01/2020` in cell `E109` and in cell `F109` insert `03/31/2020`.
- Apply cell format `mmm` on `E109` and `yyyy` on `F109`.
- An array (CSE) formula in cell `F112`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(SMALL(IF((USD-ZAR!$B$111:$B$122>=$E$109)*(USD-ZAR!$B$111:$B$122<=$F$109), USD-ZAR!$B$111:$B$122, "A"), ROWS($A$1:A1)),"")
  ```

**N.B.**

- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.
- Adjust cell references in formula as needed.

Comment: Please write your concern that,, Y this post has been down voted, just read comments above by the OP,, `extract the data in ascending order`,, your reply help me to fix it !!